# Getting error while creating workflow in Knime for text analytics

Tags: text, analytics, knime

[image]

I have a set of URL from which I have to read data and execute a particular work-flow in Knime for determining word frequency. However I am getting error "No column with DocumentCells found!". I have attached reference image. Can someone please help me with this.

Also I am getting following error in the HttpRetriver node saying

> WARN  HttpRetriever (deprecated) 0:2        Error retrieving https://www.bosch-do-it.com/gb/en/diy/knowledge/project-guides/valentine-s-day-601921.jsp: Exception java.net.UnknownHostException: www.bosch-do-it.com for URL "https://www.bosch-do-it.com/gb/en/diy/knowledge/project-guides/valentine-s-day-601921.jsp": www.bosch-do-it.com

Comment: I don't see an image here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the "Strings to Document" node to use the "POS tagger" node.
The "POS tagger" node needs a DocumentCell to work and the "Strings to Document" node do the job.

[Updated Workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pznpv.png)

Comment: Hi it is partially retriving however I am getting following error in String To Document node. please refer the attachment
http://oi62.tinypic.com/fs749.jpg

Can you please tell me how to resolve the error.

Comment: Actually I need to create a workflow in knime to crawl "https://www.bosch-do-it.com/gb/en/diy/knowledge/project-guides/valentine-s-day-601921.jsp"  and calculate TF-IDF. Can you please suggest me some sample workflow for that

Comment: Your first error is because a column named "Document" already exists in the input table of the "Strings to Document" node, thats why i put a "Column rename" node. So just rename the column named "Document" with this node and this will work.